# How can I force two decimals in Active Admin .csv export of currency data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export, activeadmin

I am using the instructions in the Active Admin ["Customize the CSV"](http://activeadmin.info/docs/4-csv-format.html) doc to change what columns are included when I export a resource index to a .csv file.

According to the doc, it's possible to set custom csv options such as `:force_quotes => true` and `:col_sep => ';'`.

How can I find a full list of these options? I am exporting a table that contains currency and when I open it in Numbers the currency cells are formatted to only include one decimal unless the second of the two decimal places is not 0. For example, the amounts $100.00 and $100.50 become $100 and $100.5 in the .csv file, but $100.75 correctly remains $100.75. I can change the cell formats in Numbers but it would be nice not to have to do it every time I export the data.

Can I include an option like the ones used as examples to force two decimal places for all values so they'll appear like they do in my AA index? And, more broadly, how would one know where to find an exhaustive list of options?

Comment: how are you confirming $100.00 is becoming $100? In raw data or in excel?

Comment: $100.00 is how $100 is appearing in Numbers (Mac spreadsheet program)

Comment: can you run `cat nameofcsv.csv` in your terminal and confirm that $100 is in there and not $100.00?  I ask because excel and other programs are known for dropping leading and trailing zeros to "save memory".

Comment: Ah, good idea. So when I use `cat` or `nano` to view the file in the terminal, the decimals appear correctly. So it's definitely the program itself that is causing the issue. But that's what I figured all along. And I can change the values for a column of cells manually in Numbers, I was hoping there might be a csv option like the ones above that would force it, but it looks like that's not going to happen?

Comment: Your csv is perfect, so if a machine reads it - you're fine.  If someone else imports it, you'll need to give them instructions about the issue.  Most excel people know about it - https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+leading+zeros

Comment: Should I recap this in an answer?

Comment: sure, that would be good

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63610/discussion-between-anthony-and-sixty4bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, the fact that this file can be opened in a text editor and shows the correct decimals means that the problem is with Numbers. Doesn't look like there's a way to do this without having to change the columns' decimals manually after exporting and opening the file.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you convert it in the csv block:

```
csv do
  column(:coloumn_name) { |my_object| my_object.currency.round(2) }
end
```